# Azure webb-app bug? Web.config getting duplicated

Tags: azure, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I'm having problem with a php app that I run on Azure. The Web.config somehow keeps getting modified into copies of itself:

This is how I found it now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="YOURLS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/yourls-loader.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="YOURLS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/yourls-loader.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Obviously this results in an error. What is happening?

Is this a bug in Azure?

Comment: Do you have any WebJobs or any triggers may have R\W operations of the files in your applications?

Comment: No it's a simple webapp

Comment: How are you / did you deploy it? And do you have any logs in the deployment process?

Comment: Simple FTP deployment. Seems like a bug in Azure? Microsoft wants me to purchase a 6 month support agreement to even report this as a bug.

Comment: You can report an issue at Kudu github

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new web app to solve the problem.